# Laravel : Create new product with category in database

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, seed

for the moment, i'am creating my product link to my category directly from my code in my seed doing 
`->categories()->attach(1)` at the end of each product.

From my database, I can create a product but i can't link them with a foreign key to a category that is already in `category_product_table`.

I have 3 table : `products`, `categories` and `category_product`.

2020_04_09_073846_create_products_table

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('slug');
            $table->string('category');
            $table->string('description');
            $table->string('releaseDate');
            $table->float('price');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

ProductSeeder

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use App\Product;

class ProductSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {

            Product::create([
                'name' => 'Halo 5',
                'slug' => 'halo-5',
                'category_id' => '1',
                'category' => 'Xbox One',
                'description' => "Halo 5: Guardians sur Xbox One est un FPS mettant en scène les aventures du Master Chief et d'un nouveau personnage, le Spartan Jameson Locke. ",
                'releaseDate' => '27 octobre 2015',
                'price' => '54.99'

            ]);
```

2020_05_02_201337_create_categories_table

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name')->unique();
            $table->string('slug')->unique();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

CategorieSeeder

```
<?php

use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\Category;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class CategorieSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $now = Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();

        DB::table('categories')->insert(
            array(
                array( 
                    'name' => 'Xbox',
                    'slug' => 'xbox',
                ),
                array(
                    'name' => 'Playstation',
                    'slug' => 'playstation',
                ),
                array(
                    'name' => 'PC',
                    'slug' => 'pc',
                ),
                array(
                    'name' => 'Switch',
                    'slug' => 'switch',
                ),
            )
        );
    }
}
```

2020_05_03_105839_create_category_product_table

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('category_product', function (Blueprint $table) {

            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Product.php

```
class Product extends Model
{
    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->AsOne('App\Category');
    }
}
```

Category.php

```
class Category extends Model
{  
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product');
    }
}
```

HomeController

```
    public function public(){

        if (request()->category) {
            $home = Product::with('categories')->whereHas('categories', function ($query){
                $query->where('slug', request()->category);
            })->get();
            $categories = Category::all();
            $categoryName = $categories->where('slug', request()->category)->first()->name;
        } else {

        $home = Product::inRandomOrder()->paginate(9);
        $categories = Category::all();
        $categoryName = 'Featured';

        }
        return view('home.index')->with([
            'home' => $home,
            'categories' => $categories,
            'categoryName' => $categoryName,
            'mode' => 'public'
        ]);
```

If someone can help me, thanks for your help !

Comment: what is the exact error do you have

Comment: I don't have any error. Is juste that when i'm creating a new product in my database, it doesn't link to the category.

Comment: what do you mean by linking to the product, foreign key?

Comment: Yes a foreign key

Comment: then add the controller that you are using to add the product

Comment: sorry i forgot to put it there ! I just edit my post with it :)

Comment: You showed wrong method. Show what you have there in creating when error occurres.

Comment: Just a tip, every changes in migration will only be effective when you run an artisan migrate command.

Comment: Please upload your seeding code, that will more helpful to understand

Comment: I updated my post with it. I add a category_id in the product table but i can't do php artisan migrate. It tell me "General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `products` add constraint `products_category_id_foreign` foreign key (`category_id`) references `categories` (`id`) on delete cascade)"

Answer (score 0):

php artisan make:migration create_products_table --create=products
php artisan migrate:refresh
use directly this command and add